# Python Kivy Panel Header unable to render content from class

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy

I am trying to create a simple `TabbedPanel` with 4 tabs. I want each tab to render the widgets from 4 classes. Kivy seems to not be rendering this simple Label. I want to do this with the libraries and not by creating a `.kv` file and importing it with `Builder.load_file(file)`. In the code I provided, I only show the default_tab. Thanks in advance.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader

kivy.require('1.10.1')

class DeployScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeployScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Deploy'))
        return(None)

class NucleusPanel(TabbedPanel):
    tab_pos = "top_left"
    nuc_panel = TabbedPanel()
    nuc_panel.default_tab_text = "Deploy"
    nuc_panel.default_tab_content = DeployScreen()

class NucleusApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return(NucleusPanel())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    NucleusApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor for `class NucleusPanel()`

## main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel


class DeployScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DeployScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Deploy'))


class NucleusPanel(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NucleusPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tab_pos = "top_left"
        self.default_tab_text = "Deploy"
        self.default_tab_content = DeployScreen()


class NucleusApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return NucleusPanel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    NucleusApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: This was so simple. Thank you so much, it works beautifully.

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). [If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Do you mind briefly explaining to me why the NucleusPanel class needs a constructor? Since the 'Deploy' tab initiates I didn't think the absence of a constructor was the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without a constructor, it will display a tabbed panel with a tab containing the text `Default tab` and an empty `content`. As per your original code, it is creating class attributes and not adding them to the instantiated object, `NucleusPanel`.